# Google Data Prep - cannot import table from BigQuery (created from Google Sheets) "Nothing found"

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I created one table in BigQuery from Google Sheets, when I tried importing it in Cloud Data Prep it says that there are no tables in the dataset.

I'm not sure whether it's an issue with the Google sheet integration, because when I check the details of the table it says there are 0 rows even though there are 3 rows (it's test data).

I already tried giving Cloud Data Prep viewer permission for both the dataset and the project and nothing changes.

Print screens:

[Data Prep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIooe.jpg)

[BigQuery table info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rykJ9.jpg)

[BigQuery entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0nIB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently when you create a table from google sheets it is not recognized as an actual table, so I made a query to replicate it to a second table and it works!